# Java - Thread join() and order of execution SCJP question?

Tags: java, multithreading, scjp

I've been doing some practice for my O/SCJP exam. Consider the following code:

```
public class Cruiser implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread a = new Thread(new Cruiser());
        a.start();

        System.out.print("Begin");
        a.join();
        System.out.print("End");
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.print("Run");
    }
}
```

Source: http://scjptest.com/mock-test.xhtml

The site states the output (the answer to their mock question) will be `BeginRunEnd` and, when running the class normally, that's exactly what is output.

However, when debugging the output is `RunBeginEnd`.

Is it fair to say that under *normal* execution, the output will *always* be `BeginRunEnd` or would this vary depending on other factors (like how *heavy* the new thread class is / how long after starting the thread it takes to join it)?

Would you say it's a fair / accurate exam question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think BeginRunEnd is more *likely* than RunBeginEnd (I'd expect the act of actually starting up the new thread to take a while before it got to the `run` method, and for the first thread to get to the print before it runs out of its timeslice in most cases), but it would be *flat out incorrect* to assume that when programming.

You should regard the two threads as completely independent as soon as `start` is called, until they're explicitly tied together again with the `join` call. Logically, the new thread could run all the way to completion before the main thread prints "Begin".

Looks like a bad question to me.

Comment: well I'm not a Downvoter however I disagree with one bit in _completely independent_. Look, there's [join()](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.5)

Answer (score 2):

This is a rubbish question. The outcome is undefined without synchronisation.

Is this really bofa fida SCJP question, or just one made up by some site trying to sell SCJP training? If its the latter then I'd avoid that site like the plague.

Comment: @Qwerty Phew, I read the first sentence and thought you meant my question for a moment. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to be platform dependant, but to show the order can change.

```
public class Cruiser implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread a = new Thread(new Cruiser());
        a.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        a.start();

        // Thread.sleep(1);

        System.out.print("Begin");
        a.join();
        System.out.print("End");
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.print("Run");
    }
}
```

prints the first time I ran it.

```
RunBeginEnd
```

however after that its mostly the BeginRunEnd

If the thread stops, even for 1 ms it will produce the RunBeginEnd nearly every time.